# let user change background on 4 different imageviews xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

im trying to make an app that has 4 ImageViews and I want to allow the user to change the background on the different ImageViews by pressing an UIButton below each ImageView. I have written a code for this from a tutorial showing to do this with just one ImageView. I just copied and pasted 4 times for each button and changed some variables. But when I run it only the first ImageView changes its picture even if I press UIButton for 2nd, 3rd or 4th ImageView. here the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController2;
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController3;
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController4;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize firstImageView, secondImageView, thirdImageView, fourthImageView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)firstChangeButton:(id)sender
{
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (IBAction)secondChangeButton:(id)sender
{
imagePickerController2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[imagePickerController2 setDelegate:self];
[imagePickerController2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController2 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (IBAction)thirdChangeButton:(id)sender
{
imagePickerController3 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[imagePickerController3 setDelegate:self];
[imagePickerController3 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController3 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (IBAction)fourthChangeButton:(id)sender
{
imagePickerController4 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[imagePickerController4 setDelegate:self];
[imagePickerController4 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController4 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];

[data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

[[self firstImageView]setImage:image1];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController2:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info2
{
UIImage *image2 = [info2 objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);
NSString *myGrabbedImage2 = @"myGrabbedImage2.png";
NSArray *path2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory2 = [path2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile2 = [documentDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage2];

[data2 writeToFile:fullPathToFile2 atomically:YES];

[[self secondImageView]setImage:image2];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController3:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info3
{
UIImage *image3 = [info3 objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *data3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image3);
NSString *myGrabbedImage3 = @"myGrabbedImage3.png";
NSArray *path3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory3 = [path3 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile3 = [documentDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage3];

[data3 writeToFile:fullPathToFile3 atomically:YES];

[[self thirdImageView]setImage:image3];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController4:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info4
{
UIImage *image4 = [info4 objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *data4 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image4);
NSString *myGrabbedImage4 = @"myGrabbedImage4.png";
NSArray *path4 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory4 = [path4 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile4 = [documentDirectory4 stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage4];

[data4 writeToFile:fullPathToFile4 atomically:YES];

[[self fourthImageView]setImage:image4];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

@end
```

How should i apply it for all 4 ImageViews?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all image pickers will call the same delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

When you set the delegate for the image picker controller like so:

```
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
```

You basically tell the image picker controller that *self* will be able to respond to the image picker delegate methods.
As you can see in the [UIImagePickerControlDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html), there's no such thing as:

```
– imagePickerController2:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
```

and so on.

As a start, I would suggest rewriting your delegate method like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];

    [data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

    if (picker == imagePickerController) {
        [[self firstImageView]setImage:image1];
    } else if (picker == imagePickerController2) {
        [[self secondImageView]setImage:image1];
    } else if (picker == imagePickerController3) {
        [[self thirdImageView]setImage:image1];
    } else {
        [[self fourthImageView]setImage:image1];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This way, all image picker images will be handled by the same method, thus reducing the amount of code.

Comment: Hope it helped! To strip out more of your code, I would recommend that you pointed all your buttons to the same action method. Then use a tags to identify which image picker to pop up. For example: `if (sender.tag == 1) { /*Show picker #1 */ } else ...` etc. (tags can be set on the buttons in the interface builder) But I guess thats a bit off topic for this specific question.

Comment: thank you it really helped but it doesnt work anymore:( can you please have a look at my newest question "cant open this app Xcode"? it would be really nice